# How to get the index values assigned to a new list?

Tags: python, list

So basically I am trying to figure out how to add the indices of the odd numbers of a list to a new list that I create in Python.

So say I have:

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_list= []
```

I want to make a for loop that puts the indices of the odd numbers in it so it should look like:

```
new_list = [0,1,3]
```

I've been trying to use enumerate to get the indices like this but can't figure out how to do it.

```
for num in original_list:
    new_list = []
    if num % 2 !=0:
         new_list = list(enumerate(original_list))
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the numbers which are < len(original_list) and are odd?

Answer (score 0):

To get the indices of the odd numbers in your list you could make a list comprehension.

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
idx = [i for i,e in enumerate(original_list) if e % 2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
odd_num = [index for index, num in enumerate(original_list) if num % 2 != 0]
even_num = [index for index, num in enumerate(original_list) if num % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_list = [original_list.index(i) for i in original_list if i%2 == 1]
print(new_list)
```